# CSV import (neo4j browser) returning empty nodes only i.e. without properties

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I am unable to successfully import a csv file in the neo4j browser, as the nodes are created but they do not show the properties. Does anyone see the problem? I will describe how I proceeded:

This is how the csv file looks

[image]

I have tested the csv file with LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///testCSV3.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 4 
RETURN line

and the result is ok (I guess?):

[image]

I then tried various things, as e.g. this query:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///testCSV3.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Activity {activityName: line.MyActivity, time: toInteger(line.Timestamp)})

The outcome is nodes without properties:

[image]

Any ideas what I am missing? Why are the properties activityName and time not showing up? - Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the CSV file, are the fields separated by a comma (",")?

Comment: Thanks, please see my comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(You should have shown your raw CSV file, to make the problem clearer.)

I assume your raw file starts out like this:

```
ID ;Timestamp;MyActivity
1;1;Run
2;2;Talk
3;3;Eat
```

`LOAD CSV` is sensitive to extra spaces, so your `ID` header should not be followed by a space. Also, the default field terminator is a comma not a semicolon, so you need to specify the `FIELDTERMINATOR` option to override the default.

Your results would be more reasonable if you removed the extra space and changed your query to this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///testCSV3.csv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH line LIMIT 4
RETURN line
```

Comment: Thank you very much again. I created the csv file in 'numbers' on a Mac. There is a possibility of saving a table as a csv file. I thought that was fair enough and therein was my problem.